# When do nested promises need to be returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When chaining multiple `then` statements, I'm struggling to understand when I need to return a value to the next `then` statement vs when it's automatically passed down. The confusion (for me) is when I have a promise inside a `then` statement vs not.

This is in a node environment - an express app (more specifically, a Firebase Function triggered by a HTTP request) - so I'll ultimately `res.send()` some value.

```
// Do I need to return mainFunction()?
mainFunction()
  .then(resultOfMyFunction => {
    // I want the next "then" to wait for the response from this block
    // Do I have to return asyncFunction() or just the value below?
    asyncFunction().then(resultOfPromise => {
      // Do I return resultOfPromise?
    }).catch(error => {
      // If I return this error, will it go to the mainFunction catch block?
      return error
    })
  }).then(resultOfPromise => {
    // This is blocking, so the next "then" should wait for the value
    return synchronousFunction(resultOfPromise)
  }).then(resultOfSynchronousFunction => {
    // End of function - do I need to return resultOfSynchronousFunction?
  }).catch(error => {
    // Do I need to return error?
  })
```

I know we shouldn't nest promises, but Firebase doesn't really give us an option when you need to chain multiple, different database calls where each call is a promise and you need to wait for data from one to call the next.

Comment: The second outer `.then()` will not wait for `asyncFunction()` to complete if you don't return it from the first outer `.then()`.

Comment: The answer is don't nest promises. Chain them. if you do `return asyncFunction();` then the `then` can live outside of the function and it's easier to read

Comment: So I would need to return `resultOfPromise`, but do I also need to add `return` before `asyncFunction`? Or will the second outer then wait for `asyncFunction` automatically?

Comment: *"will it wait automatically"*...No. it will run that function and immediately run the next `then()` where `resultOfPromise` will be undefined

Comment: `synchronousFunction` seems problematic. If this doesn't return a promise you need to wrap it in one if you want to consume if in this manner.

Comment: @Liam - are you saying this can be rewritten as `mainFunction().then(resultOfMyFunction => {return asyncFunction()}).then(resultOfPromise)`

Comment: Many of the questions you ask here should be answered when reading a tutorial on promises, no?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want something like this. I'm presuming that by `This is blocking` you mean `synchronousFunction` is not async. In which case it does not need to be consumed in a promise like fashion.

```
mainFunction()
  .then(resultOfMyFunction => {
    //return promise from async function
    return asyncFunction();
  })
  .then(resultOfPromise => {
    let resultOfSynchronousFunction = synchronousFunction(resultOfPromise);
    // End of function
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Do I need to return error?
  });
```

if you want to return `resultOfSynchronousFunction` then you should read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

If you want to return an async version of `synchronousFunction` you'll need to wrap this in a promise:

```
mainFunction()
  .then(resultOfMyFunction => {
    //return promise from async function
    return asyncFunction();
  })
  .then(resultOfPromise => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let resultOfSynchronousFunction = synchronousFunction(resultOfPromise);
       // End of function
       resolve(resultOfSynchronousFunction);
    });
  })
  .then(resultOfSynchronousFunction => {})
  .catch(error => {
    // Do I need to return error?
  });
```

If you want to run another async call after `synchronousFunction` a better pattern would be:

```
mainFunction()
  .then(resultOfMyFunction => {
    //return promise from async function
    return asyncFunction();
  })
  .then(resultOfPromise => {

       let resultOfSynchronousFunction = synchronousFunction(resultOfPromise);
       // End of function
       return anotherAsyncCall(resultOfSynchronousFunction );
  })
  .then(resultOfanotherAsyncCall => {})
  .catch(error => {
    // Do I need to return error?
  });
```

Comment: But if I want to use the result of `synchronousFunction` in the next `then` statement, I can `return synchronousFunction(resultOfPromise)` and the next `then` will be blocked until `synchronousFunction` is done?

Comment: In your code there is no next `then`? Promises (async functions) do not block. synchronous functions block. I'm not really clear what your getting at?

Comment: Sorry. If I want to use `resultOfSynchronousFunction` in another `then` block (let's say I have three more `then` statements to run, that very next `then` block will wait until `synchronousFunction` is complete and I return that to the next `then`?

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in a promise, I've added code for you to show this. Note that `synchronousFunction` will never block in this scenario

Comment: Got it! So everything inside a `then` statement must be a promise, and I can return the async function and pull my `then` and `catch` up so I'm not nesting. Thank you - it's clear now!

Comment: I was about to upvote this and then I saw you added the `new Promise` inside the `then` stuff which doesn't actually do anything other than create a superflous promise and assimilate it.

Comment: I did not downvote, but wrapping the synchronous function in a `new Promise` is an antipattern.

Comment: OP seemed quite clear that they wanted this. I'm not clear why either but `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` *If I want to use resultOfSynchronousFunction in another then block*

Comment: You can use a synchronous function in another then block or wrap it in a Promise.resolve instead of a `new Promise`

Comment: @Liam is right about what I was asking. How would I use the result of a synchronous function and pass that to the next `then` statement if not via a promise?

Comment: @Joe-NewNine I'm guessing you have other async blocks? I've added a cleaner implementation which addresses the (correct) anti pattern comments

Comment: You can just return the value of the synchronous function. You can return *any* value in a `then` callback, even if you don't it will be the `undefined` value... whatever. The `then` method had already created a promise, so it just fulfills with that value and initiates the next `then` in the chain. The special case is in fact when you *do* return a promise in a `then` callback. ;-)

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 2):

> The confusion (for me) is when I have a promise inside a then statement vs not.

Whenever you have a promise inside a `then` or an async function you *must* return to it. Otherwise rejections (thrown errors in async functions and promises) get swallowed and end up in the global hook without giving a chance to whomever is calling your code to handle the error.

Synchronous functions have no such limitation - returning a synchronous code only matters if you want to reuse its return value since thrown errors are handled by the `then` automatically.

> ```
>   // If I return this error, will it go to the mainFunction catch block?
> ```

Promises are really quite non-magical. The return value is how the error/success (rejected/fulfilled) state is propagated between calls so if you don't return the value - mainFunction won't go to its catch block.

If you want it to go to its catch block - the return value needs to be a promise that eventually rejects - for that you need to either rethrow the error in the inner `.catch` block or remove the `.catch` from there altogether.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I was stuck on how to un-nest promises and the effect of synchronous functions inside `then` statements, but I get it now thanks to you and Liam's example.

Comment: @trincot not misleading - just wrong, I missed that in the question. Fixing, thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Could you provide a link or explanation why a promise inside a then (or async function) needs to be returned? I currently tried to "dispatch" a Promise whose result isn't of interest for me. So I just called it inside my async function without awaiting it (but try-catched it to log the error). The result is that my app just crashes without any error. And I really would like to know the mechanics behind the scenes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds weird and like some place in your code is throwing an error outside the call stack (like in a timer) - I'd recommend looking at the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your support. And yes. After some changes I noticed that there is an error thrown. It is confusing that I don't get the usual "UnhandledPromiseRejection". Inside a `then` I call a function which returns a Promise. I add a catch call and don't return it. I was hoping that thus I would handle the rejection but don't need to wait for the Promise settlement to continue the outer Promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the anonymous functions in the first two `then()`

You can do it by passing function references to `then()` instead

```
mainFunction()
  .then(asyncFunction)
  .then(synchronousFunction)
  .then(resultOfSynchronousFunction => {
    // consume resultOfSynchronousFunction or return to next then()
  }).catch(error => {
    // Do I need to return error?
    // only if this is not final catch block
  })
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!